# Convergence of $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt{a_{n}}}{\ln\, n}(n^{a_{n}}-1)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

If $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}a_n$ converge, then also converge this series?
$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt{a_{n}}}{\ln\, n}(n^{a_{n}}-1)$$

Please verify my answer below

Counterexample:

$$a_{n}=\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{k^{2}} & n=k!^{k^{2}}\\ \\
0 & \text{All other cases}
\end{cases}$$

When our infinites sum is equal to

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k}\cdot\frac{1}{2\, \ln\, k}\cdot(k!-1)$$

Comment: OK, solution moved to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The denominator $2\log k$ is supposed to be $\ln n$ but if $n=(k!)^{k^2}$, then $\ln n=k^2\ln(k!)$. Since this is equivalent to $k^3\ln k$, the counterexample holds nevertheless.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your counter-example is correct, so your solution is correct.

Comment: This should be a comment as opposed to an answer.

Comment: Why?  It is an answer after all.

Comment: Both true and false.

Answer (score 1):

For large values of $n$,

$$n^{a_n}-1={1+a_n{\ln\, n}}-1 =a_n{\ln\, n},$$

so the given series becomes

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt{a_{n}}}{\ln\, n}(n^{a_{n}}-1)=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt{a_{n}}}{\ln\, n}(a_n){\ln\, n} = \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}{a_n}^\frac{3}{2},$$

which converges , if
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_{n}{\ln\, n}=0
$$

Comment: This only holds if $a_n\log n$ is small. As OP's example shows, where $a_n$ is small for very large $n=(k!)^{k^2}$, this is not necessarily true.

Comment: yes, if the limit of $a_n log(n)$ tends to zero, to be exact